# How to Change Add New Item url of List View Webpart 

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a list. I created a webpart for insert item to it.

I created a page to add webpart.

I want set this page for NewForm of list.

I use sharepoint designr, but when i edit allitems form don't show additem button !

How to change the url of AddItem button to this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find answer. This [link](http://ovaisashraf.blogspot.com/2011/06/change-add-new-item-text-of-list-view.html) is useful.

1. Open Page in SharePoint Designer 2010
2. Open List and then choose the View on which you want to change the text.
3. Switch to Design mode and select List View web part.
4. Now You should see List View Tools on SharePoint designer ribbon, select Design from it.
5. There is a section called “Toolbar”, and an “option” dropdown is there, change options from “None” to any other option. Now You should see “Add New Item” link on Design View.
6. Select “Add New item” and click just after this link and wait for the vertical cursor to appear, this will cause the web part to Load on that page.  SharePoint Uses Web parts references on the pages and the data with the web part is rendered at runtime.
7. When cursor appears, just press any key so that it gets written on that page. Now Switch to code view.
8. Delete the key that you have pressed :)
9. Now look just before the cursor (where you have delete the pressed keys),  you may have the following code in front of you:

   a class="ms-addnew" id="{$ID}"
                href="{$Url}"
                onclick="javascript:NewItem2(event, "{$Url}");javascript:return false;"
                target="_self">
               
             /a>
10. Remove “xsl:value-of select="$AddNewText" /” and write your text that you want to display on the link.
    Save the page.

Answer (score 1):

You add a new "Add" form in SharePoint designer but when you add it, remember to check the box marked "Set as default form for the selected type". Add your new webpart to the newly created form.

[image: Adding new "new" for in SPD]

[image: Editing the new "new" form in SharePoint to add your custom webpart]

Comment: Thanks, but i created a webpart for newform, and add it to a page. i want set this page to new form.

Comment: You need to edit the page created in the step above to add your new web part. Once you have followed the above step, go to the new "new" page, you should get the standard popup dialog to enter the new listitem details. Right click properties on that popup, you should see the url is your new page e.g. newform2.aspx. Copy this URL and put it in the browser with the dlg=1 part taken out. Now do Site Actions -> Eit Page, you should be able to edit the web parts on your new "new" page. Close the existing web part (do not delete it), add your custom web part and save the page.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot here of me editing a new "new" form I created for an out of the box calendar list, you would close the existing webpart and add your own.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i created a page and add webpart but i want change url of AddItem in allitems page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in sharepoint designer, sorry I cannot find the screenshots for the steps right now, but I find a related artical may help you:
[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/ec2769a0-683c-4023-8804-b596e4f92a3a/)